# writing Hindu–Arabic numeral in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, numbers, editor

I'm working on tcpdf for pdf auto generation. I need to printout numbers in hind arabic numerals but no editor I have tried can do that.

I tried notepad++, windows built in notepad, hosting online editor. it is always displayed in English

```
$this->Cell(13, 0, '(008)', 0, 0, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
```

I need it to be displayed in hindarabic numerals

Comment: Where? Expected output and on what device? Browser?

Comment: Windows, local php, notepad++ editor

Comment: Do you mean instead of '(008)' you want to output '(۰۰۸)'? And where you are trying to show this? in output HTML file? or in the output PDF generated by TCPDF?

Answer (score 0):

I found this function which solved my problem

```
function arabic_w2e($str){
 $arabic_eastern = array('٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩');
 $arabic_western = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
return str_replace($arabic_western, $arabic_eastern, $str);
}
```